# Unable to update each column of Parse Object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am updating an object. I first find it by doing the following:

****EDIT****

*Additional code added for setting and saving the object.*

```
    var query = new Parse.Query(iBeacon);
    query.equalTo("uuid", searchUUID.children("input[type=text]").val().toString());

    query.find({
        success: function(results) {

       var detailsObject = results[0];

       //tduuid, tdoffer, tdproximity etc are globals intitialized earlier in code
       //from values obtained from html table cells
       var uuid = tduuid.children("input[type=text]").val().toString();
       var offer = tdoffer.children("input[type=text]").val().toString();
       var prox = parseInt(tdproximity.children("input[type=text]").val().toString());
       var campaignId =tdcampaignId.children("input[type=text]").val().toString();
       var location = tdGeoLocation.children("input[type=text]").val().toString();
       var subLoc = tdinStoreLocation.children("input[type=text]").val().toString();

        detailsObject.set("proximity", prox);
        detailsObject.set("campaignId", campaignId);
        detailsObject.set("location", location);
        detailsObject.set("sub_location", subLoc);
        detailsObject.set("uuid", uuid);

        detailsObject.save(null, {
            success: function(detailsObject) {

                var content = Parse.Object.extend("Content");
                var contentQuery = new Parse.Query(content);
                var id = detailsObject.id;


                //Querying Content Table on detailsObject to obtain correct record

                contentQuery.equalTo("descId", detailsObject);
                contentQuery.find({

                    success:function(contentObject){

                        contentObject[0].set("offer", offer);
                        contentObject[0].save(null, {
                            success: function (result){
                                //alert("offer saved successfully");
                                document.location.reload(true);

                            }, error:function(error){
                                alert("unable to save offer");
                            }
                        });
                    },error: function(error){
                        alert("Error  "+ error.message);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error.code + " , " + error.message);
            }
        });

  },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
});
```

So you can see I queried the column "uuid" in the iBeacon class. I am updating based on data entered into an html table by the user. I can update every other column but I can't update my "uuid", I am guessing that as this is part of the query I can't do it this way? I have tried this by finding the object with different parameters and it's that in particular that can't be updated....I need to update this and I'd appreciate any help on it.

***FURTHER EDIT***

I have been trying out things on this and have since noticed that if I put a hard coded string into where I set the uuid i.e. `detailsObject.set("uuid", "UUID EDIT");` this works correctly, however, when I set uuid with the value obtained from the table cell is doesn't proceed.  I have debugged it and the correct values are obtained.  For testing, I queried the categoryId, when I tried to update the categoryId it wouldn't work either, but if I updated the uuid or any other columns without updating the categoryId, there was no problem.

Using a different editor I get an uncaught TypeError when debugging `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`

Comment: add the code where you're updating and saving the value.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of is that Parse strings are case sensitive. If you store them as lower-case, you need to search using lower-case.

With something like your `uuid` field you can force the input to lower/upper case before writing it, and then also force user input used for search to lower/upper case as needed.

Comment: hi Timothy, the searching isn't the problem, I can obtain the object successfully, it's when I try to update the object I encounter the issue, all columns update successfully, however when I try to update the column that I have used in the query to obtain the object, in this case 'uuid' that's when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved this myself.  This issue was indeed that when searching the query was taking in the edited uuid and not the original uuid, there was a mix up with initialisation with javascript.

So I needed to store the original uuid(which was pulled from parse) as a global string variable.  I had stored it incorrectly.

Thank you everyone for your help